# How to replace 'example.com' with my IP for the reset password link

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am using the django inbuilt auth urls and views for the user login/logout/passwordreset/

namely,
in the urlpatterns

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

in my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import *
```

after enter the email address for resetting password, I could receive the email with the link to reset password, but the link would be similar to  `http://example.com/accounts/reset/s-3is-7535266db5af311b2a02/`

and after manually change the 'example.com' to my IP address(as I am running the server on my localhost), I could change the password as well as login with the new password.

I have read the Django auth codes and understand that if no override given, it would take domain of the current site and set it as'domain' in the `PasswordResetForm`

what am I supposed to do to make the link works fine so that after click on the link it would successfully direct to the django url to change the passwor.

(I am thinking of override django's induilt PasswordResetForm in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py but the only thing I think I need to change is the 'domain_override=None' but then I would still have to keep the whole save function code. but this definitely is not the best way)

thank you for helping suggesting other ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default domain in the [`sites` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) is called `example.com`. You'd have to change that.

Comment: Yea, I have changed the site domain name in the admin site apps and it is working now. Thanks Burhan.

Comment: This is not very helpful. It does not provide specifications on how to change it. I fact, it was clear before that something has to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Django use `django.contrib.sites` framework to determine the default `site_url`, by default, `site_url` is `example.com`.

A better way to do this is use django "initial data" feature, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/.

For example, you can create an `initial_data.yaml` file in your `django_app_dir/fixtures` directory, the content of `initial_data.yaml` may be:

```
- model: sites.site
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: 'example.com'
    domain: 'example.com'
```

Then you can just do a `python manage.py loaddata initial_data.yaml` after `python manage.py syncdb` or just `python manage.py syncdb` if this is the first time you initialize db.

Answer (score 0):

Django by default add **example.com** to app sites. You can refer to the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/). You'd have to change this while using the email sending part which includes your domain name.

To solve the issue, you need to set your domain-name (without protocol) in admin sites.